# Swift - Container view across multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Desired Effect:**

I would like for the user to be able to swipe between 2 view controllers, while having 1 large container view over top. This can be better explained visually through the image below.

[image: Here]

It is important that the bottom view (VC C) remains the width of both the other views (VC A and VC B). Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: you can add the vc c on window of the app.that will make it stick on top.

Comment: is there any specific reason to use 3 view controller? You may use same VC  in scrollview/collectionview

Comment: @SurjeetSinghRajput That might work. Would it be possible to have VC C on the window of the app, but then also have content from VC A (such as a table view) over top of VC C?

Comment: @AdiHardik I believe so. I'm trying to have a tab bar with VC A and VC B as the tabs (and a swipe gesture to move between the tabs), then have an image (a car) drive from one end of VC C to the other end. I would like to have the car image continue moving across VC C even if at the given time it is not in frame.

Comment: Basically you want this without the menu on top: https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu